# Getting incorrect returned values from assembly to C

Tags: c, assembly, arm64, calling-convention

I am calling `push` and `pop` (from my assembly code) in C like so:

```
int main()
{
    push(8);
    push(1);

    push(pop() + pop());

    return 0;
}
```

But I don't get the correct values when I do `push(pop() + pop())`. When debugging in `gdb` for `push` I get

```
=> 0x4008a8 <main+420>: add     w0, w19, w0
(gdb) p $w0
$16 = 8
(gdb) p $w19
$17 = 4325452
```

As you can see, `w0` gives me the correct value of `8` but `w19` gives me `4325452` when it should be `1`. Probably because my first returned `pop` value isn't saved in `main`.

Here are my `push` and `pop` subroutines in assembly:

```
push:       stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
            mov     x29, sp

            mov     w9, w0                                      // 1st operand: int f (input)

            adrp    x19, sp_m
            add     x19, x19, :lo12:sp_m                        // load address of sp                            
            ldr     w22, [x19]                                  // load sp

            cmp     w22, MAXVAL                                 // compare sp to MAXVAL
            b.ge    push_ge                                     // if sp >= MAXVAL, stack is full so branch to push_ge

            ldr     x21, =val_m                                 // load address of val array into x21

            str     w9, [x21, w22, SXTW 2]                      // store value of f in array, using val_m as the base and sp_m as the offset

            add     w22, w22, 1                                 // sp++
            str     w22, [x19]                                  // store sp back

            b       push_ret   

push_ge:    adrp    x0, str1
            add     w0, w0, :lo12:str1
            bl      printf
            bl       clear  

push_ret:   ldp     fp, lr, [sp], 16
            ret





pop:        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
            mov     x29, sp

            adrp    x19, sp_m
            add     x19, x19, :lo12:sp_m                        // load address of sp                            
            ldr     w22, [x19]                                  // load sp

            cmp     w22, 0                                      // compare sp to 0
            b.le    pop_le                                      // if sp <= 0, stack is empty so branch to pop_le

            sub     w22, w22, 1                                 // --sp
            str     w22, [x19]                                  // store sp back

            ldr     x21, =val_m                                 // load address of val array into x21

            ldr     w0, [x21, w22, SXTW 2]                      // load last value in val array, using val_m as the base and sp_m as the offset

            b       pop_ret

pop_le:     adrp    x0, str2
            add     w0, w0, :lo12:str2
            bl      printf
            bl      clear

pop_ret:    ldp     fp, lr, [sp], 16
            ret
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: The problem  is that [registers x19 to x29 are callee-saved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM_(A64)). For your locals you should use registers x0-x15 or make sure you save and restore the callee-saved registers. As it is, the compiler relied upon `x19` not being changed by your function during the second `pop`, but of course you did mess the value up.

Comment: I understand, but since I'm doing `pop() + pop()`, these values are being returned from `w0`. I think that since both get set to `w0` the second `pop()` overrides the first, and so `x19` is used. I do not know how to tune my assembly code to fix this.

Comment: Do what I told you to. The compiler knows that the result from the second `pop` will be in `w0` too so it moves the first one away into `w19` **expecting that to be unchanged as per calling convention**. However you destroy that, breaking the code.

Comment: Related: [What are callee and caller saved registers?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9268586)